# can not reset my google password

Tags: google-drive

I have gone around and around trying to reset my password.  I have repeatedly gone through the reset stages and I never get the email from you to reset my password.  over and over I wait for your response and I never get it. 
I have the same email address and cannot remember my password  everything else is still the same   still I do not ever receive the password reset   I get nothing from you
bmarrs@bcmvco.net

Comment: I have done what you ask for and still can not reset my password    really you have it set up so I cannot get help

Comment: I need help how --- how am I to reset my password when it is so  convoluted I keep answering your stupid meaningless questions and keep going around in circles   not helpful

Comment: Who are you mad at? Not the random strangers on this site who offered suggestions, right?  We aren't Gmail support. Did you contact them?

Comment: Please note that this is not Google Support. I suggest checking out the site [tour] to learn more.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried resetting your entire Google account via dashboard?

Comment: Kinda hard to do if you can't log in.

Comment: I meant can you attempt the reset at the Main dashboard, the account https://accounts.google.com/signin/recovery site.

Comment: That's important information that should be in your answer, not in the comments. Comments are meant to be temporary.

Comment: I'm new to the site, I apologize.  Just trying to be helpful.

Comment: @Ryan_D No worries and no harm done.  We just like to have self-contained answers to the questions.  In this case, we have a duplicate that covers most of the common answers to this question.